# Noise sender function in TOR?

Tags: attacks, routers

Does TOR have the service of contacting me with x bytes of noise and ignore the garbage I return?

*Background*

I recently heard a talk about a company that is privacy aware. They run smart thermometers using an app. Their current setup they have dedicated noise machines to send noise to the thermometer, so an attacker will not be able to see if this was a real request or not, and thus will not be able to see if I am on vacation.

If we want privacy we also must make it hard to see if there is any communication at all, so I am thinking this is a general problem. Maybe a function for the thermometer to say to the Tor network: Please send a garbage request to me from 3 hops away at this time with this length.

Comment: This is already covered in the [FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#SendPadding) and the question is already asked [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13185/making-data-transactions-ambiguous/13187#13187)